# Longitudinal data model with heavy skewed data

Tags: time-series, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, skew-normal-distribution

I have 8 months of data for three groups (which belong to the same product) with three different measurements and one independent variable. I would like to perform a hierarchical multilevel model to check statistical differences over time (considering time as the repeated measure and measurements as co-factors). The distribution of none of measures is normal. The data is heavy skewed and tailed. These are not outliers and I can't simply remove them, and I prefer to stay away from transforming the data for the sake of easier interpretations (my audiences have no statistical background).

Is there any way I can perform the test on this data? Or is there any alternative approach?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

[image]

And Here is the plot of transformation Log+1

[image]

Comment: What does the data represent? ( Y axis)  what differences do you care about? Differences in mean, median, quantiles,...?

Comment: There are three different machines of more or less the same kind. The independent variable is cost. I have measures of usage of the machines and number of site visits for repair (so two measures). I am looking for differences in means and what is affecting changes in cost (if there is statistically any).

Comment: Thanks. If it's cost then I would still suggest a log transform of your data as then differences become % changes , which is often a more natural way to compare cost measures for stakeholders/decision makers ( no need to have statistical background; just basic economics is enough) .  Lastly, just showing these boxplots on log scale would help you get a better grasp of similarity/ differences at quick glance as well

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not sure if log transform works on this data. There plenty of zero cost machines. I got Log+1 and still the data is not normal. Sorry to bother you again, would you see any solution? I am posting the plot of transformation also

Comment: This is a case of zero inflated lognormal data. This is a common model for lifetome value . Take a look at https://github.com/google/lifetime_value/blob/master/README.md . In EDA you can plot the proportion of zeros per group and the boxplots on log1p scale.  For modeling use the algorithms above and the machines/days as features

Comment: Thanks millions!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of zero inflated lognormal distribution/ data generating process, which is a common model for lifetime value. Take a look at [github.com/google/lifetime_value/blob/master/README.md](https://github.com/google/lifetime_value/blob/master/README.md). In EDA you can plot the proportion of zeros per group and the boxplots on log1p scale. For modeling use the algorithms above and the machines/days as features; then you can use bootstrap or bayesian inference to test differences among machines/days.

For decision making it depends on your downstream use case if you care about mean spend, > 0 spend, or tail risk differences